# How to position this flexbox child depending on presence of another child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a quick follow up to my earlier question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741336/how-to-push-flexbox-child-to-the-bottom-of-its-container).

I'm trying to position a flexbox child element depending on whether another child is present or not.

Best visualised in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/VPPoJN)

In some panels, ICON3 will not be loaded. The container receives a class of `hidden` and I can choose to hide it with `display` or `opacity` etc.

I'd like ICON4 to stay on the right, and to move up in line with ICON2, and for the wrapper to resize accordingly. But I can't seem to get it working.

What I've tried:

`opacity: 0` - this keeps ICON4 on the right, but does not resize the wrapper, as ICON3 still exists and takes up space.

`display: none` - this just moves ICON4 to when ICON3 was.

Also tried styling combinations using `.hidden + .four` but I can't find a working solution.

Would appreciate any help!

Snippet below:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
.image {
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.more {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 4em;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  /*display: none;  // this pushes ICON4 underneath */
}
.hidden + .four {
  /*margin-bottom: 1.4em; // this seems to position .four correctly, but doesn't alter height of .wrapper */
}
.four {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.ideal {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: -44px;
}
.ideal span {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: .2;
  margin-right: 4em
}
.ideal {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 32px;
  right: -201px;
}
.ideal span {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  opacity: .2;
  margin-right: 4em
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x68" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>Text content</span>
    <span>Text content</span>
    <span>Text content</span>
    <div class="more">
      <span class="one">ICON1
      </span>
      <span class="two">ICON2</span>
      <span class="three hidden">ICON3</span>
      <span class="four">ICON4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ideal"><span>ICON4</span>&lt; ideal position and wrapper to resize</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overlooked the height rule on `.more`

I don't think I change this with css as it's a parent, but with javascript I can add a class to `.more` and override the height.